# Ubuntu 16.04.1 wifi interface lost after restart

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager

My usb stick Belkin Components F7D1101 v1 Basic Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU] worked fine when upgrading from ubuntu 12.04.1 to ubuntu 16.04.1. But after shutdown and restart there was a problem with booting ubuntu. Wireless network was not started or offered.

This seems to be a problem with network-manager.

I implemented a script within /etc/rc.local

service network-manager restart

This seems to wake up the wifi device.

Is there a regular solution within ubuntu?